# Unexpected console.log output for nested array

Tags: javascript

```
let fee = [[2], [[123],[1233, [[123, "abc"], ["test"]]]],[123]];
console.log (fee);
```

The above code generates the following output:

```
[ [ 2 ], [ [ 123 ], [ 1233, [Array] ] ], [ 123 ] ]
```

It is displaying the first and second level of nesting of the array fine, but the third level and beyond, it just outputs "Array". Do you know why this is?
PS: The code works fine in Scrimba and in https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/
However, in my VScode installation, it's doing this weird thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to click on `Array` in console and expand it

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, does it matter?  Nothing programatically is going to be useing output in the console in other parts of the app.  It's just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

How the output is presented heavily depends on the execution environment and its developer tools.
If you want to make sure it always gets printed, you could use  [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
let fee = [[2], [[123],[1233, [[123, "abc"], ["test"]]]],[123]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(fee));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention it, but this happens in node, the output of nested elements in the browser is different than in node (to check run your example in the browser devtool console), to see the same result in both environments use `consolo.dir()`, Please look at the example

```js
let fee = [[2], [[123], [1233, [[123, "abc"], ["test"]]]], [123]];

console.dir(fee, { depth: null, color: true });
```

See

- [console.dir.options](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am running node. Sorry for not pointing that out in the OP.
However, using console.dir() , the nested arrays still output the same way. It just says something like:
{
    name: 'Adlam',
    ranges: [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ],
    direction: 'rtl',
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet'
  }

The [Array] is actually number ranges, but gets outputted as "Array" for some reason.

Comment: have you used `console.dir()`, with the suggested `options`? I mean `console.dir(fee, {depth: null, color: true});` I am using it right now on node and the output I get is this https://imgur.com/7P1YnKu